# how to get user Access token in facebook using java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get user AccessToken of fb using `REST API` programatically in `java` using emailid and password for multiple user.I am making `javaFX` Desktop application to post a message in all the user wall. here any other api is available to get Access token at run time. I have also use Facebook4j api but not get any solution to getting User access Token not App Access Taken.

Here I see the code that is using access Token

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

But it's not showing how to get User Access Token using desktop Application.
It is possible or not?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-devices/ is your friend, unfortunately this login flow is not for general use. So, what you can do is open up a web browser from your java program for authorization step.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the OAuth login flow to get an User Access Token. You can find an example app here: https://github.com/roundrop/facebook4j-oauth-example

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

but i want to make desktop application.and your example are used jsp and servlet it's required server to execute. here it's any api there i can pass email and password and get access token.

Thanks

Comment: No, there's no such way.